# Extract year, within bandwith, in text using regex in R

Tags: r

I need to extract the years (vintage of whisky) out of the String. but only value between the years 1900 and 2017. Would somebody help me to find out the regex expression? thank you

Comment: Which "String"? Can you please be a little more specific, providing some illustrative data?

Comment: let's say a vector with the two following examples: c("Ardbeg, 1974 Vintage, Cask #3145, 49.9%", "Dun Bheagan (distilled at Springbank), Cask No. 1704, 35 year old, 1970 vintage, 50.5%"). As you can notice there are the number of cask as well. Using only the regex "\\d{4}" does not help me to make the distinction between year number and cash number. Hence, my question: how can i capture number falling within a bandwidth?

Comment: Please see my edit using your text string as well as a little addition ot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a string like this:

```
txt <- c("Ardbeg, 1974 Vintage, Cask #3145, 49.9%", 
         "Dun Bheagan (distilled at Springbank), Cask No. 1704, 35 year old, 1970 vintage, 50.5%",
         "Someotherstuff, Cask #1234, 200 years old, 1820 vintage, 99.9%")
```

To extract the years of interest (between 1917 and 2017) you can first extract **all** years using `str_extract_all` from `stringr` as well as negative lookbehind in `(?<!(No.\\s|Cask #))`, which **prevents** matching if `No.\\s` or `Cask #` appears to the left of `\\d{4}`:

```
library(stringr)
years_all <- as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(txt, "(?<!(No.\\s|Cask #))\\d{4}")))
years_all
[1] 1974 1970 1820
```

Then, to isolate the years of interest, you can subset `years_all` accordingly:

```
years_all[years_all >= 1917 & years_all<=2017]
[1] 1974 1970
```